# How can I lay out a grid to space out labels to the left and right?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code I have:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="noa">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Hide Card After" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Picker x:Name="noaPicker" IsVisible="false" SelectedIndexChanged="noaPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"></Picker>
      <Label x:Name="noaLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
      <Label Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FAAngleRight}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
Hide card after             2 points >
```

However what I get is Hide card after, 2 points and the > are almost all on top of each other.

Can anyone help and suggest how I can achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: What information handles the `noaLabel` ? Also, the picker is the one showing `2 points` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Column number for each element.

```
<ViewCell x:Name="noa">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Hide Card After" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Picker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="noaPicker" IsVisible="false" SelectedIndexChanged="noaPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"></Picker>
      <Label Grid.Column="2" x:Name="noaLabel" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
      <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FAAngleRight}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```